# When using pdfpages in LaTeX, how to avoid page breaks before the first page ?

Tags: pdf, latex

I am creating a large LaTeX document, and my appendix has reproductions of several booklets that I have as PDFs. I am trying to create a section header and then include the pages at a slightly lower scale. For example:

```
\section{Booklet about Yada Yada Yada}

\includepdf[pages={-}, frame=true, scale=0.8]{booklet_yadayada.pdf}
```

However, pdfpagex does two annoying things. First, it devotes one output document page for included document page. I can live with that as I am using 80% scale. The main problem, however, is that the first page is also a new page, so I have a page with just a section title, and then a separate page with the booklet.

Is there some way to get pdfpages to be a little smarter here?

Comment: wrt your comment on jleedev's post, have you tried putting {1-} as your pages?

Comment: This question belongs to http://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`\includepdf` uses `\includegraphics` internally, so something like

```
\section{Foo}
\fbox{\includegraphics[page=1,scale=0.8]{foo.pdf}}
```

would include the page without starting a new one, although it only does one page at a time.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using your trick for the first page, and then adding the other pages with one call to includepdf (putting {2-}) as my pages.

Comment: I think you do not need the fbox environment, at least that is the case for other pages than before the first page. My solution **\includegraphics[page=1,scale=0.8,trim=20 20 20 20,clip]** and works fine without a page break.

Comment: `includegraphics` seems to add a layout to included pdf, at least the left margin is too large, like page 1 is pushed to the right.

Answer (score 12):

For me the following worked just fine:

```
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand=\section{Section Heading}]{testpdf}
\includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand={}]{testpdf}
```

Comment: The heading went over included table in a pdf: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-01%20at%2019.08.57.png Can you customise the position of the heading and included pdf document?

Comment: @Masi, use the `scale` option to shrink the graphics.

Comment: Example with a section header and scale:

`\includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.8,pagecommand=\section{Your Section Title}]{your.pdf}`
`\includepdf[pages=2-,scale=0.8,pagecommand={}]{your.pdf}`

Answer (score 8):

I tried this solution too, but `\includepdf` keeps the advantage of outputting the file over the margin (the output is centered from the edges of the page).
So I openned pdfpages.sty, and I searched for `\newpage` command. I deleted the first occurance (line 326), just to try, and after saving then compiling again, there were no page break anymore.

Comment: Excellent - thanks for that. I managed to find a copy of pdfpages.sty [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty) and removed the line you mentioned (line 327 on this one) and it saved faffing with the `\includegraphics` and getting the correct scale etc. Also lets me choose what documents to use it on as I just drop it in the same folder as the .tex file for it to be used.

Answer (score 4):

Use the minipage environement :

```
\chapter*{Sujet du stage}
%\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\includepdf[scale=0.8]{../sujet-stage/main.pdf}
\end{minipage}
```

It doesn't add any extra page and it works with includepdf.

Comment: This is a great solution if one doesn't want to use `pagecommand` or can't as it's in my case where a custom `\section` throws an error if passed to the `pagecommand` parameter. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the answers - I couldn't for the life of me figure out what logic `\includepdf` uses to insert blank pages; the trick with including the first page via `\includegraphics` solved most (but not all) of those problems; so here are some notes:

First, out of curiosity, I have also tried to use only `\includepdf`, but split in two parts:

```
\includepdf[pages=1]{MYINCLDOC.pdf} 
\includepdf[pages=2-last]{MYINCLDOC.pdf}
```

... unfortunately, this has the same problem as the question in OP.

- Since [@WASE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6682142/277826)'s answer, there are now multiple `\newpage`s in the source (`pdfpages.sty`). I tried reading the source, but I found it quite difficult; so I tried temporarily setting `\newpage` to `\relax` only for `\includepdf` - and that puts all pages in the document on top of each other; so probably not a good idea to get rid of `\newpage` blindly.
- Just `\includegraphics[page=1,scale=0.8]{foo.pdf}` works - but (as [@WASE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6682142/277826) also note) it is aligned at the top-left corner of the page *body*, which is to say inside the margins; for a full page we'd want the pdf inclusion overlaid over the whole page, margins included.

This page: [graphics - How do I add an image in the upper, left-hand corner using TikZ and graphicx - TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38751/how-do-i-add-an-image-in-the-upper-left-hand-corner-using-tikz-and-graphicx) points to several possibilities for positioning on page over the margins; but for me, the best solution for a full page PDF inclusion is to use package `tikz` to center it to the page:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[page=1]{MYINCLDOC.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\includepdf[pages=2-last]{MYINCLDOC.pdf}
```

After this is done, as a bonus, I have also experienced:

- Proper targets of PDF bookmarks (going to the right page when clicked)
- If you use package `pax`, the data seems to be included also for the `\includegraphics` standalone first page, so no difference there
- If you have a twoside document - `pdfpages`, with the above split of the first page in `\includegraphics`, will now (seemingly) correctly insert the equivalent of `\cleardoublepages` between pdfs that are included back to back (so I don't have to insert such a command manually).

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

Comment: Yes it did help, as I had the chapter title (Curriculum Vitae) already on that PDF, and I wanted to link from ToC to this page. Hence I introduced a `\chapter[Curriculum Vitae]{}` before including the PDF. Unfortunately the PDF has been put always on the next page. With your tikz approach, everything works: brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late, but the following solution worked for me:

```
\includepdf[pages={-},angle=90, scale=0.7]{lorem-ipsum.pdf}
```

All pages are imported, scaled and rotated by 90 degrees.
Works with Texmaker 5.0.4